# Set default parameter of a function as an array

Tags: c++, arrays, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Default values for array arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093700/default-values-for-array-arguments)

How do I give an array as the default parameter to a function? I tried this:

```
void drawCircle(float radius, GLfloat colour[3]={2.0, 3.0, 4.0}, bool do=true) {
...
}
```

The part `GLfloat colour[3]={2.0, 3.0, 4.0}` gives me an error. Is this possible in C++?

Comment: You can never pass an array as an argument. What you pass is a pointer to the beginning.

Comment: It is a duplicate, but it doesn't deserve the downvote. +1 for karma.

Comment: Yes, the answer accepted is very different too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot pass an array by value, and so you cannot do that.

So the workaround is, overload the function as:

```
void drawCircle(float radius, GLfloat *colour, bool pleaseDo) 
{
  //...
}
void drawCircle(float radius, GLfloat *colour)
{
  drawCircle(radius, colour, true);
}
void drawCircle(float radius) 
{
   GLfloat colour[3]={2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
   drawCircle(radius, colour, true);
}

drawCircle(a,b,c); //calls first function
drawCircle(a,b);   //calls second function
drawCircle(a);     //calls third function
```

Second and third function eventually call the first function!

Also note that `do` is a keyword, so you cannot use it as variable name. I replaced it with `pleaseDo` :D

Comment: pleaseDo? Sounds like [INTERCAL](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/INTERCAL). +1

Comment: Anonymous downvotes are nuisance. I will nullify that, because your answer is correct. One small thing, since the OP is particular about array size 3, I think you can make the 2nd argument as `GLfloat (&color)[3]`; isn't it

Comment: Thanks! Should it be: `drawCircle(radius, &colour, true);`? Does the `colour` needs to be passed by reference?

Comment: @xEnOn: No. `colour` is an array of type `GLfloat[3]` which will decay into pointer type `GLfloat*`.

Comment: @xEnOn, if you are particular about array size 3 then, make the definition as `drawCircle(float radius, float (&colour)[3], bool pleaseDo);` and No, you don't have to pass in a special way; just pass as it is

Answer (score 7):

In C++, You cannot pass a complete block of memory by value as a parameter to a function, but You are allowed to pass its address.

So NO, you cannot do that atleast in C++03.

You can do this:

```
GLfloat defaultColor[3] = {2.0, 3.0, 4.0}; 

void drawCircle(float radius, GLfloat colour[3]= defaultColor, bool do=true)
{
}
```

Comment: defaultColor should be declared as an array of GLfloat.

Comment: Assigning a global variable will not be thread safe and the array size of global should be `3` (you mistakenly put it as `2`).

Comment: `return 0;` for void function?

Comment: @iammilind: Geez, I have butter fingers today :P. Thanks for the correction on Typo. For the first comment, For a start We don't know OP has an multithreaded enviornment

Comment: Still there is a problem. OP wants to pass always `{2,3,4}` when the function is called. Also `colour` is passed as modifiable pointer to array. Suppose, if the value is modified then it will reflect in global array `defaultColor[]`, so from then onwards wrong array will be passed !

Comment: @iammilind: I guess If one wants to twist around with the semantics then one has to be careful with it. Language allows you to shoot yourself in the foot, If you are hell bent on doing so.

Comment: @iammilind: the type `GLfloat` comes from the OpenGL libraries, and arrays of colors are received by the library as non-const pointers to non-const `GLfloat` even if the library does not change the contents. Since the functions will (assumptions and hand-waving here) change the passed in array, it should be safe in a multithreaded environment (regarding your first comment), and changing it to a pointer to const `GLfloat` will force the user to add `const_cast` internally (regarding last comment)... It is always hard to work with libraries that are not designed with const-correctness in mind...

Answer (score 2):

You can define your default value as a global variable. Then, use this global variable as default argument to the function.

```
GLfloat default_colour[3] = {2.0, 3.0, 4.0};

void drawCircle(float radius, GLfloat colour[3] = default_colour, bool doit = true)
{
}
```

Btw, `do` is a keyword, you cannot use it as a parameter name.

Answer (score 1):

You can't quite do what you want to do but this solution works on my compiler:

```
static GLFloat DefaultColour[]={2.0,3.0,4.0}
void drawCircle(float radius, GLfloat colour[]=DefaultColour, bool do=true) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the [Initializer Lists](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#init-list) feature from C++11 can help in your question.

```
void drawCircle(float radius, std::initializer_list<float> colors = {0.9f, 0.2f, 0.7f}, bool do=true)
{

    if (colors.size() == 3)
    {
        // parse the values...
    }

...
}


// and then...

drawCircle(10.0f);
```

Unfortunately I'm not sure that this feature is up on your compiler :(