# C# COM functions with default array parameter set to null

Tags: c#, com

I was moving my code from VSTO to ExcelDna and I face a strange error.

I created in Visual Studio a new project which will contain my previous VSTO functions. In order to generate the .tlb file which I will then reference in Excel VBA to get access to these functions in VBA, I checked the option "Register for COM interop"

For one function I have the error:

"The assembly "C:\MyProj.dll" could not be converted to a type library. Type library exporter encountered an error while processing 'GetArrayObject'. Error: Type mismatch."

The definition of the function GetArrayObject in the Com visible interface is:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
//[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IAddInUtilities
{
    object[,] GetArrayObject(string[] rows = null);
}
```

The following definition works:

```
object[,] GetArrayObject(string[] rows);
```

Is it a known limitation in COM? Can it be due to the limitation in C++ ([Default values for array arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093700/default-values-for-array-arguments))? Is there a reason it works for VSTO and not for COM?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a great error message.  You can see the problem when you run Oleview.exe File + View Typelib on your working version of the interface.  You'll see:

```
interface IAddInUtilities : IDispatch {
    [id(0x60020000)]
    HRESULT GetArrayObject(
                    [in] SAFEARRAY(BSTR) rows, 
                    [out, retval] SAFEARRAY(VARIANT)* pRetVal);
};
```

Note how the string[] is marshaled as a SAFEARRAY, the standard Automation type for arrays.  And note how it is passed by value, not by reference.  Which means that it can't be null.  There's otherwise no support for specifying a default value for a SAFEARRAY.

You'd have to pass the array by reference, *ref* keyword in C#.  But then you'll run into a problem with the C# language rules, you cannot specify a default value anymore.

Next attempt is to force the array to be marshaled as a pointer, BSTR*.  That's rather the antipode of a SAFEARRAY, for one you now have to add an extra argument to state the number of elements in the array since the COM server can't figure it out anymore from a plain pointer.  Like this:

```
public interface IAddInUtilities {
    object[,] GetArrayObject(
        int rowcnt,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]string[] rows = null
    );
```

Which converts just fine.  However, when you now look at the type library with Oleview.exe, you'll see:

```
interface IAddInUtilities : IDispatch {
    [id(0x60020000)]
    HRESULT GetArrayObject(
                    [in] long rowcnt, 
                    [in, optional, defaultvalue("")] BSTR* rows, 
                    [out, retval] SAFEARRAY(VARIANT)* pRetVal);
};
```

Ugh, wrong default value.  The only other option you've got is to use the IDL you get from Oleview.exe, edit it to change the defaultvalue(), compile it with midl.exe to generate the type library and use Tlbimp.exe to generate an interop library.  Which you can then add to your project with Project + Add Reference.  Not exactly so sure that this is still worth the hassle of a minor convenience, it is up to you to make the call.